Fill in skylight opening without drywall
Need to fill in removed skylight opening in living room ceiling.  Plan to edge in moulding and putting lauan with insulation and caulk.  There in no insulation on exposed roof.  Should i also insulate that and with what? Will this work?

it is unclear what you are trying to do ... please add pictures

How do you add picture?  Opening in ceiling is 22x44.  I am going to move up in opening 2 inches to make a rim around the inside with molding.  Sitting above that will be lauan and insulation.

FYI: Lauan is a type of Asian wood used to make plywood. Yes, this will work. Make the rim large enough so that it can support the infill plywood. Cut the plywood slightly smaller than the actual opening and insert the piece diagonally into the opening. Rotate and lay the piece good side down on top of the rim.

insulate with similar material to the rest of the roof insulation

Opening at the roof line is not insulated.  I plan to add insulation to that also.
